# Docker: ubuntu:22.04 (ubuntu:latest) fails at apt update

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, deployment

Running:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:22.04 /bin/bash
apt update
```

Fails with:

```
22.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:7599221e4e2e4eeb90ad282fc523139578f3dfea245b5049c4fee1b28776d2be
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:22.04
root@117960ca68dd:/# apt update
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
Fetched 20.2 MB in 2s (9747 kB/s)                       
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Pulling ubuntu:21.10 still works fine.

What is causing this and how can it be avoided?

Been using docker:latest since over a year and 1st time things completely broke down during a new deploy due to the assumption that an official docker image 'just works'.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Upgrading docker to the latest version should help.

Comment: Just curious, why allow docker related questions at all on stackoverflow cause none will be purely programming related? (Issue is still unresolved but seems to be caused by the Ubuntu:latest Tag being upgrade to the latest Ubuntu LTS release)

Comment: This question/answer may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408528/apt-update-on-ubuntu22-04-results-in-error-100-on-some-docker-hosts And, note that stack overflow is for programming problems, where ask ubuntu, server fault, and other variant sites, are more suited to devops/sysadmin questions.